# Dropping a foreign key constraint in Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-migrations

I have two tables:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    pass

class Bar(models.Model):
    foobar = models.ForeignKey(Foo, unique=True)
    barfoo = models.ForeignKey(Foo, unique=True)
```

Validation ensures that there is never a `Foo` that is both a `foobar` and a `barfoo`.  I need to delete the `Bar` model and all `Foo`s that are `barfoo`s.  My approach is to remove the foreign key constraint from `Bar.barfoo`, run some SQL to delete all `Foo`s that are a `barfoo`, then to delete the model.  I can't seem to find anything in the django migration docs for removing Django's dynamically-generated foreign key constraints, though.  Ideas?

Comment: Having gotten no response, I've implemented a workaround by copying over `foobar_id` to a temporary integer field then dropping the foreign key field entirely.  It would still be nice to have a more direct solution.

Answer (score -1):

Create a migration that drops 'foobar' and alter 'barfoo' adding a CASCADE DELETION behavior. Run this migration, delete all Bar objects in the database, then finally delete the Bar model from your model file and generate a new migration.

Make sure you don't have any generic foreign keys on your model (or you will get stale data on django_contenttypes table).

That's it.